# Woes dealing with syntax error while using Promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am an "old school" system analyst / programmer and I've struggling for days with a problem related to Promises in Javascript. I am at my wits end ...
Here's the code I am having problems with:

```
          return fetch("bad://" + url)
                 .then((response) => {
                     var subst = response;
                     if (!response.ok) {
                        var emsg = "<span style='color:red'><b>ERROR</b></span>[" + response.status + "]: " + url;
                        subst = new Response(emsg, String);
                     }
                     return subst;
                  })
                 .then(response => response.text())
                 .then((html) => {
                     return extractHtml(html, url);
                  })
                 .then((html) => {
                     if (!el.parentNode) {
                        return;
                     }
                     el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html.repeat(repeat));
                     el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                     return(url);
                  })
                 .catch((error) => {
                     console.error('Failed to fetch(): ' + error.message);
                     return;
                  })
```

I keep getting a SYNTAX ERROR stating "unexpected token ')'". I need help to figure out why there's a syntax error im the code above. For that matter, the code is being used in a web page.
Funny enough, the following code does NOT yield a syntax error (??):

```
          return fetch("bad://" + url)
                 .then((response) => {
                     var subst = response;
                     if (!response.ok) {
                        var emsg = "<span style='color:red'><b>ERROR</b></span>[" + response.status + "]: " + url;
                        subst = new Response(emsg, String);
                     }
                     return subst;
                  })
                 .then(response => response.text())
                 .then((html) => {
                     return extractHtml(html, url);
                  })
                 .then((html) => {
                     if (!el.parentNode) {
                        return;
                     }
           
           el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html.repeat(repeat));
           el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
           return(url);
```

Yes, '"bad://" + url' is coded on purpose in order to test error handling.
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: There's no syntax error in that block of code.

Comment: The error message should tell you which line the error is on. And if you click on the line number it should take you directly to the bad code, and it will show a squiggly line under it.

Comment: The problem could be due to what's on the lines before this. Can you post the entire function?

Comment: Try adding more error handling. The `reponse.ok` property indicates the args passed to `fetch` were acceptable and that a network error did not occur - it _does not_ mean the server didn't send an error response using an HTTP error code such as 404 or 501. You can check for server errors using  `response.status` and `response.statusText` [instance properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_properties)

Comment: I finally managed to figure it out by myself, folks! Never mind. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The way you are injecting status & url values into `var emsg` is [potentially dangerous](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/11-Client-side_Testing/03-Testing_for_HTML_Injection).

Comment: Hi, @jarmod ... Thank you for your input / feedback but I beg to disagree ... neither status nor URL come from unreliable sources and therefore I can't figure how come they would be a risk for HTML injection

Answer (score 1):

Folks, never mind ... in the meantime I finally managed to figure it out. By no means I am a Javascript person (sigh) and because of that I was coding the ".catch()" method at the wrong place ... For what it's worth, the "fixed" code ...

```
          return fetch(url)
                 .then((response) => {
                     var subst = response;
                     if (!response.ok) {
                        var emsg = "<span style='color:red'><b>ERROR</b></span>[" + response.status + "]: " + url;
                        subst = new Response(emsg, String);
                     }
                     return subst;
                  })
                 .then(response => response.text())
                 .then((html) => {
                     return extractHtml(html, url);
                  })
                 .then((html) => {
                     if (!el.parentNode) {
                        return;
                     }
           
          el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html.repeat(repeat));
          el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
          return(url);
         
        } // importForElement(el)
       
      )  // class HtmlImport
                 .catch((error) => {
                     console.error('Failed to fetch(): ' + error.message);
                     return;
                  })
```